# How to use WCF as a bridge or wrapper?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf

I have a special service constantly outputting updates from the field 24/7. Since it's using the push mechanism and proprietary, it requires its corresponding proprietary client to receive the updates. I am not sure if this is a right approach, but I was asked to write a WCF service exposing the received data as a web service in JSON. What I am thinking is to write a web service wrapping a constantly-running process receiving updates and cache updates in memory and whenever my web service is called I will throw the cached data back in JSON.

As I understand, the ServiceHost is not constantly running. Instead it is activated when somebody hits the service. That's not ideal because we need to receive all data (or at least data of last X days).

I also welcome any different approach if the current one sounds idiotic.

fredell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF supports [self-hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx), which basically lets you do whatever you want.

You could write a Windows service application which hosts the WCF service. The Windows service would run continuously and receive the proprietary push notifications, and the WCF service hosted inside would let you access the received data.

This approach seems fine to me, but beware of memory exhaustion: maybe you'd want to persist the received data in some time-series database, so it doesn't get lost if your service crashes - and your service wouldn't consume lots of RAM if no-one actually polls the data through WCF.